# Can WCS and REST be written and consumed in PHP

Tags: php, rest, saml-2.0, wcs

I am new to php, i have to consume a API written in .NET with REST and WCS as a service provider.
Also the SSO with SAML2 has to be there.
Frankly speaking i have no idea about what is REST and WCS. 
While i see that SAML2 is supported in php.
Can somebody help if REST and WCS is supported in PHP? 
I ma googling to get basic idea about what it does but could not find  how to do it in php.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

RESTful APIs in WCS v7 FEP7 opens up options to build store-websites using any web programming language and on any web framework while taking advantage of enterprise grade business logic in WCS.

I was part of a PoC to use python (Django) as an alternative over a year ago -- it is very easy and works great. Consuming REST service was just two lines of code:

```
sampleResponse = urllib2.urlopen('<STORE_URL>' + '/<URI>');
sampleJSON = json.load(sampleResponse);
```

I am sure PHP (SAML2), Ruby (Rails) should all work just as well.

Some things to remember:

- WCS support will not extend to custom technologies - so you will need to extend your own support for store front issues.
- You will need to separately size and plan for the horse power required to run your    favorite runtime.
- I suspect that you will most likely miss out on Commerce Composer feature (or at least requires additional customization there).
- You may also need to manage SEO differently - not via WCS Management Center.

There may be others.